# GetItem and PutItem from table in dynamodb to put Json string

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to put item in Json format using below approach using AWS SDK for dotnet core but Its not able to find method GetItem/PutItem

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-json.html

MY Code is

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model;
using Amazon.Runtime;
```

[image]

While using putItem as below I am not getting error but item is not inserted into table
[image]

table on AWS dynamoDB
[image]

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: yes , Finally was able to work few min back. used PutItemAsync, GetItemAsync and for put ,json string must contain the primary key value and sort key as well if it was defined